# Organizing a classification tree (in rpart) into a set of rules?

Tags: r, classification, cart, rpart

Is there a way that once a complex classification tree is constructed using rpart (in R), to organize the decision rules produced for each class?  So instead of getting one huge tree, we get a set of rules for each of the classes?

(if so, how?)

Here is a simple code example to show examples on:

```
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data=kyphosis)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such a functionality (or a close one) seems to be available in the [rattle](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rattle/index.html) package, as described in [RJournal 1/2 2009](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2009-2/RJournal_2009-2_Williams.pdf) (p. 50), although I only checked it from the command-line.

For your example, it yields the following output:

```
 Rule number: 3 [Kyphosis=present cover=19 (23%) prob=0.58]
   Start< 8.5

 Rule number: 23 [Kyphosis=present cover=7 (9%) prob=0.57]
   Start>=8.5
   Start< 14.5
   Age>=55
   Age< 111

 Rule number: 22 [Kyphosis=absent cover=14 (17%) prob=0.14]
   Start>=8.5
   Start< 14.5
   Age>=55
   Age>=111

 Rule number: 10 [Kyphosis=absent cover=12 (15%) prob=0.00]
   Start>=8.5
   Start< 14.5
   Age< 55

 Rule number: 4 [Kyphosis=absent cover=29 (36%) prob=0.00]
   Start>=8.5
   Start>=14.5
```

To get this output, I source the `rattle/R/rpart.R` source file (from the source package) in my workspace, after having removed the two calls to `Rtxt()` in the `asRules.rpart()` function (you can also replace it with `print`). Then, I just type

```
> asRules(fit)
```

Comment: Is it possible to print rules for non-terminal leaves as well?

Answer (score 5):

The
[rpart.plot](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rpart.plot)
package version 3.0 (July 2018) has a function
`rpart.rules` for generating a set of rules for a tree. For example

```
library(rpart.plot)
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data=kyphosis)
rpart.rules(fit)
```

gives

```
Kyphosis
    0.00 when Start >=      15
    0.00 when Start is 9 to 15 & Age <  55
    0.14 when Start is 9 to 15 & Age >=       111
    0.57 when Start is 9 to 15 & Age is 55 to 111
    0.58 when Start <  9
```

For more examples see Chapter 4 of the
[rpart.plot vignette](http://www.milbo.org/doc/prp.pdf).

Comment: Awesome reference, it would be also very helpful to have leaf number next to the rule

Comment: Use `rpart.rules(fit, nn=TRUE)` to get the node numbers (aka the leaf numbers).